# Function returns None after wrong input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need a function that excepts wrong input and asks to input once more. But after wrong input it returns `None` instead of new input. What is wrong with my code and how can I solve this?

```
def start():

    def inputNumber(answer):
        try:
            number = int(input(answer))
            if number <= 100 and number >= 0:
                print('%%%',number,'%%%')
                return number
            else:
                inputNumber('Number is wrong, please input number from 0 to 100: ')
        except (ValueError):
            inputNumber('It is not a number, please input number from 0 to 100: ')
    
    def checkInput(number2):
        print('$$$',number2,'$$$')
        if number < 50:
            return number2
        else:
            return checkInput(inputNumber('Input number from 0 to 100: '))

    number = 0
    print('###',checkInput(inputNumber('Input number from 0 to 100: ')),'###')
    start()

start()
```

This is the result:

> Input number from 0 to 100: 777
>
> Number is wrong, please input number from 0 to 100: sadf
>
> It is not a number, please input number from 0 to 100: 17
>
> %%% 17 %%%
>
> $$$ None $$$
>
> TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < int()

Comment: Sorry function checkInput() is wrong, but it doesn't matter it returns None anyway.

Comment: In Python `return` is explicit. you have to return the result of a function. Add `return` before `inputNumber` in `else` and `except`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `inputNumber` recursively but don't return the result of the recursive call. Better use loops instead of recursion:

```
def inputNumber(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            number = int(input(prompt))
            if 0 <= number <= 100:
                print('%%%',number,'%%%')
                return number
            prompt = 'Number is wrong, please input number from 0 to 100: '
        except ValueError:
            prompt = 'It is not a number, please input number from 0 to 100: '
```

Btw: you should also use loops in your other functions, and don't define nested functions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that once you fail a check you call `inputNumber` again, but don't do anything with the answer. You need to return it.

```
def start():

    def inputNumber(answer):
        try:
            number = int(input(answer))
            if number <= 100 and number >= 0:
                print('%%%', number, '%%%')
                return number
            else:
                return inputNumber('Number is wrong, please input number from 0 to 100: ')
        except (ValueError):
            return inputNumber('It is not a number, please input number from 0 to 100: ')

    def checkInput(number2):
        print('$$$', number2, '$$$')
        if number < 50:
            return number2
        else:
            return checkInput(inputNumber('Input number from 0 to 100: '))

    number = 0
    print('###', checkInput(inputNumber('Input number from 0 to 100: ')), '###')
    start()

start()
```

Answer (score 0):

run this code it will solve your problem. you just need to catch as extra error (`NameError`)

```
def start():

    def inputNumber(answer):
        try:
            number = int(input(answer))
            if number <= 100 and number >= 0:
                print('%%%',number,'%%%')
                return number
            else:
                inputNumber('Number is wrong, please input number from 0 to 100: ')
        except (ValueError, NameError) as e:
            inputNumber('It is not a number, please input number from 0 to 100: ')

    def checkInput(number2):
        print('$$$',number2,'$$$')
        if number < 50:
            return number2
        else:
            return checkInput(inputNumber('Input number from 0 to 100: '))

    number = 0
    print('###',checkInput(inputNumber('Input number from 0 to 100: ')),'###')
    start()

start()
```